# tkinter, button that adds its label to Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Pardon me if this is a bad question, I'm still learning python. I am trying to get my buttons label to show up on my entry by clicking the button, but it is showing up as !button(button number). How can I fix this? Here is a MWE:

```
  from tkinter import*
   def buttonEntry(button,rowNumber,columnNumber):
       def clickEntry():
           mainEntry.insert(0,button)
       button=Button(root,text=button,command=clickEntry)
       button.grid(row=rowNumber,column=columnNumber)
   root=Tk()
   mainEntry=Entry(root)
   mainEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)
   buttonEntry("Label",1,0)
   root.mainloop()
```

I tried moving the definition around, and looked up the problem on the internet, including reviewing the list of similar question. I am hoping to have the button variable show up in the mainEntry. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way for me to upvote your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your reuse of the name `button`.  You do pass it in as a parameter, but then you overwrite it with the `Button` object, and that's what gets inserted.  Just use different names for those two things.